# What does $\int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1} \int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}$ mean in this Fubini's theorem?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, notation, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm reading Chapter 4 in Brezis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*.

---

Let $\left(\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{M}_{1}, \mu_{1}\right)$ and $\left(\Omega_{2}, \mathcal{M}_{2}, \mu_{2}\right)$ be two measure spaces that are $\sigma$-finite. One can define in a standard way the structure of measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ on the Cartesian product $\Omega=\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}$.

**Theorem 4.4 (Tonelli).** Let $F(x, y): \Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function satisfying

- $\int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}<\infty$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega_{1}$
  and
- $\int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1} \int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}<\infty$.
  Then $F \in L^{1}\left(\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}\right)$.

Then $F \in L^{1}\left(\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}\right)$.

**Theorem 4.5 (Fubini).** Assume that $F \in L^{1}\left(\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}\right)$.

- Then for a.e. $x \in \Omega_{1}$, $F(x, y) \in L_{y}^{1}\left(\Omega_{2}\right)$ and $\int_{\Omega_{2}} F(x, y) d \mu_{2} \in L_{x}^{1}\left(\Omega_{1}\right)$.
- Similarly, for a.e. $y \in \Omega_{2}$, $F(x, y) \in L_{x}^{1}\left(\Omega_{1}\right)$ and $\int_{\Omega_{1}} F(x, y) d \mu_{1} \in L_{y}^{1}\left(\Omega_{2}\right)$.
- Moreover, one has
  $$
  \int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1} \int_{\Omega_{2}} F(x, y) d \mu_{2}=\int_{\Omega_{2}} d \mu_{2} \int_{\Omega_{1}} F(x, y) d \mu_{1}=\iint_{\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}} F(x, y) d \mu_{1} d \mu_{2}.
  $$

---

**My question:** I usually see the notations
$$
\int f d \mu \quad \int_X f(x) d \mu (x) \quad \int_X f(x) \mu(dx).
$$

Therefor the symbol
$$
\int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1} \int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}
$$
looks like the product of $\int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1}$ and $\int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}$ to me. However, this interpretation does not make sense. Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Comment: $\int_{\Omega_{1}} d \mu_{1} \int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}
$ is same as $\int_{\Omega_{1}} [\int_{\Omega_{2}}|F(x, y)| d \mu_{2}] d \mu_{1} 
$.

Comment: What geetha said. Just to add some clarification: When dealing with several iterated integrals, some authors feel like it's clearer to write the measures first because you can more easily pair a given measure with a given measure space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure

$$\int_{\Omega_1}\mathrm{d}\mu_1\int_{\Omega_2}\lvert F(x,y)\rvert~\mathrm{d}\mu_2=\int_{\Omega_1}\left[\int_{\Omega_2}\lvert F(x,y)\rvert~\mathrm{d}\mu_2(y)\right]\mathrm{d}\mu_1(x).$$